# VS Code terminal showing ERROR on every line with oh-my-posh

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, oh-my-posh

My terminal in VS Code has since the previous update shown the word `ERROR` on every single line. I have  installed `oh-my-posh` a little while back to make the terminal more pleasant to look at and give me some basic information.

Does anyone know where to look, to find the source of the error message? Tyvm :)

[image: error showing on the right side of bash terminal]

### Update

Noticed something different when running `echo $` as suggested by @kamen-minkov

When I booted Ubuntu up again and my VS Code opened from the previous state it was in the `ERROR` label was gone:

[image: image showing no error label]

However. When I opened up a new tab it returned:

[image: the return of the error label]

The only difference I can notice between the two is that there is a little, unfilled, circle/dot on the left side of the newly opened tab and not the one that opened up with VS Code. Is it some sort of debugger marking or something else? Could it be the source of the problem?

Comment: What does executing `echo $?` in the same terminal give you?

Comment: updated my post with some more details @KamenMinkov :) but the `echo` command just writes a new line with a dollar sign on it and then the next command line looks like the examples shown above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it's the Shell Integration decorations that's causing the hazards..

```json
// settings.json

"terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": false,
"terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.decorationsEnabled": "never",
```

disable these settings and `oh-my-posh` error label will be gone :)

[image: vscode settings decorations]

Comment: That fixed it for me (VSCode, bash terminal on WSL2, Oh My Posh). Thanks!